# Use jwt token to get orders for a current user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have the following GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = OrderScopes.ProviderUserScopeName)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllOrders()
{
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

return Ok(await _mediator.Send(new GetAllOrdersQuery()));
}
```

If I run the above API I get all orders but I need to return the orders for the current user.

I have created `accessToken` to get the jwt token, but I got stuck here.

Do you have any ideas how can I get the orders for the current user?

Comment: You should have a middleware that performs the authentication automatically.

Comment: The authentication works well. But I need to make the above GET method to retrieve orders for a user and see on jwt the current user. So a user can see only his orders.

Comment: If it works well, then why don't you get the user via `HttpContext.User...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this is done in middleware before it even reaches your controller method.

But if you want to do it by hand, you first need to validate the JWT `access_token` extracted from your HTTP header. Failing to validate JWT tokens correctly is a common (and extremely dangerous) security issue.

To validate, use a `ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>` to retrieve the up-to-date signing keys, and then use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to actually validate the token. Be sure to use an up-to-date library version (avoiding the noop-algorithm security bug); and set `ValidIssuer`, `ValidAudiences`, `ValidateIssuerSigningKey`, and `IssuerSigningKeys` appropriately.

Once the JWT token is validated, then you will receive a `ClaimsPrincipal` as a result. On that principal is a claim with the name `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`; that is the unique identifier for that user. That's the identifier you should store or map somehow to an identifier used in your system.